# Wordpress include scripts and style in plugin page

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I am working on a Wordpress plugin where I want to include some jquery scripts and stylesheet. I found dit piece of code in an article and this should do the job, but it doesn't work for me. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
// Include files
function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_style( 'filename.css', plugins_url('filename.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'filename.css' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_scripts');
```

Comment: Are you trying to include the files on the front end, or on the back end plugin page?

Comment: With your code, `filename.css` should be in the same directory where the file having the above code is present. Is this correct?

Comment: @s_ha_dum In the back end of the plugin page.

Comment: @Chittaranjan Yes it's in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) is a front-end hook. It will not execute on the back-end. You need to use [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) instead. This is even mentioned on the Codex page just refrerenced.

See also:

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Administration_Side